# Admob ads loads on debug but won't load in production

Tags: android, admob, ads, error-code

So I created the adMob account and set everything right, google send me an e-mail saying that my account was configured and ready to publish ads.
Then I did the configuration on my app and tested it just fine by debugging on Android Studio, not publishing, with addTestDevice and without - I know I shouldn't do this, but I just loaded so I could make it sure it was ok.
But when the app was uploaded to production, and installed the app from there, it start receiving ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL error (I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3).

I know that this error happens when adMob doesn't have an ad to send, but how come it work on debug mode and not in production?

This is the error:

> 12-06 10:20:21.535 15899-15899/? D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
>   12-06 10:20:21.537 15899-15899/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0DAAEFF66CB80E873C75B4912371F7BC") to get test ads on this device.
>   12-06 10:20:21.611 17128-15073/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
>   12-06 10:20:21.663 17128-16126/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14799021.14300000.1
>   12-06 10:20:22.084 15899-15899/? I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

This is the code I use to call the ads, it is static for I use it on another Fragments/Pages of my app:

```
public static void adViewSetup(View mview){
    final AdView madView = mview.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice("9C1E05D53A952405B2A66A70E846F862")
            .build();
    madView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

This is an example of how I call my addViewSetup on the onCreateView:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_home, container, false);
Home.adViewSetup(view);
```

This a sample of my add on xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/adView"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:adUnitId="@string/adId"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Solution

> So, the solution was... Waiting.
>  The ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL (ad Failed to load 3) means that the server is responding but you'r account doesn't have a inventory of ads build yet. It seems like this inventory is created after a few users start to use your app, and consequently sends ads request to adMob server.
>   For me, it took 2 days for the ads to start appearing after going into Production.
>   I hope this post would be of help for those who are in doubt just as I was.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different device dont intall in debug mode

Comment: Tried a different device, did not work... Now get this, the same version I uploaded on the play store works if I install it by sending directly to my phone by usb. What the heck?!

Comment: let me install your app from playstore name of your app?

Comment: It was enabled only for Brazil, I enabled for other countries now but it may take a while to appear for you.
This is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rafaelcaldas.rh_clculosalarial

Comment: Ads just started to appear, I read somewhere that the ads only started to appear after the server receives a X number of requests, so it just needed time.